# Curly/Bendy Vector in Tikzpicture

Tags: vector, latex, tikz

I'm trying to create a sort of "vortex" downward vector in my Tikzpicture diagram. I looked up similar code for bending vectors, but don't know how to particularly change the details too well. I attached an image of what I am trying to attain and drew it in with red. I would attach code, but the entire diagram is quite lengthy. If someone could explain more how to bend the vector in a particular direction.
[image]

Comment: maybe have a look at the coils from the `3dtools` package (https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools/blob/master/3DToolsManual.pdf)

Comment: Will do! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a plot of a trigonometric function to swirl down there:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\x{1}
  \newcommand\y{1}
  \draw [scale=1, domain=-360:2250, samples=1000, smooth, variable=\t, red, thick] plot ({\x+ sin(\t)*(1-\t*0.0003)}, {\y +cos(\t)*(.3-\t*0.0001)-\t*.001});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The commands `x` and `y` can be used to set the absolute position of the figure. `scale` is for size. The other parts are of course variable as well but it takes some time pruning.

The code above results in the following:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much!